# Python: create list of values from matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I'm doing some analysis of neuron synchronization in python, and I have a matrix that shows a synchronization value as a function of time, R(t), for multiple trials. My matrix therefore has the following look:

[image]

The subscript on the R indicates the trial number, and the subscript on the t represents the time point. I would like to create an array (call it L) where the first entry in L is the first time when R1 reaches a certain value, the second entry in L is the first time when R2 reaches a certain value, and so forth. So for a more concrete example, let's say I have 10 trials and 15 time stamps:

```
import numpy as np

R = np.random.rand(10,15)
print R
```

How would I go about creating my array L (which will be of length 10) from R so that I can record the first time that each row in R reaches a value greater than 0.4? I can then use this code with the data tables I have which are too big to post on stack overflow.

Comment: You probably don't need to convert to a list to do any post-processing, but anyway `R.tolist()` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread your question. Fortunately the kind free code writers didn't disappoint.

Comment: @AndrasDeak It's alright. I appreciate though you showing me the tolist function since I've never seen it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import numpy as np

# for reproducibility
np.random.seed(0)
R = np.random.rand(10, 15)

# your threshold
val = 0.7
```

Now you can use `nonzero` to find the indexes of entries that are larger than this threshold:

```
a1, a2 = (R > val).nonzero()
```

This can be combined to row-column-pairs (I removed a few to save space):

```
pairs = zip(a1, a2)

[(0, 1),
 (0, 7),
 (0, 8),
 (0, 10),
 (0, 13),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 ...
 (7, 13),
 (8, 0),
 (8, 2),
 (9, 5),
 (9, 8),
 (9, 9),
 (9, 10),
 (9, 12),
 (9, 13),
 (9, 14)]
```

You always want to find only the first occurrence, so we check where the row index jumps:

```
target_indexes = np.where(np.diff(a1) > 0)[0] + 1
```

As we then miss the first index, we add the index `0`

```
target_indexes = np.insert(target_indexes, 0, 0)
```

Now we can just select all our indexes:

```
first_occurence = [pairs[ind] for ind in target_indexes]
```

In this case we would receive:

```
[(0, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 7),
 (4, 6),
 (5, 14),
 (6, 3),
 (7, 4),
 (8, 0),
 (9, 5)]
```

whereby the first value of the tuple is the row and the second value is the column index.

You can the extract the column index easily doing a list comprehension:

```
[pi[1] for pi in first_occurence]
```

which gives

```
[1, 2, 1, 7, 6, 14, 3, 4, 0, 5]
```

Comment: Wow this is really nice, thank you! This question might be really stupid, but is there a way after you have the first_occurence term, to extract the second column of the times? I'm wanting to do some statistical analysis with the column index

Comment: @Brenton: Yes, see my edit. If the answer is helpful, please also upvote it :)

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! This just saved me a lot of time towards finishing my degree haha

Comment: Seems much more complicated than the pure numpy solution below.

Answer (score 0):

```
R = [ ... ] # Function list
T = [ ... ] #
L = []
threshold = 0.4
for r in R:
    found = None
    for t in T:
        if r(t) > threshold:
            found = t
            break
    L.append(t)
# L should have for each r (in R) the value of t (in T) when r(t) > threshold, or None otherwise
```

if you need the "t-index" instead of the "t-value", look into `enumerate` and adapt the code

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(9)
# input array
R = np.random.randint(13,42, size=(4,6))
# timestamps
t = np.arange(0.,R.shape[1])
#threshold array
thresh = np.random.randint(13,42, size=R.shape[0])
# create 2D array for timestamps along columns, threshold along rows
T,Thresh = np.meshgrid(t,thresh)
# set timestamps where R is smaller than thresh to nan
T[R<Thresh] = np.nan
# from remaining timestamps get minimum
v = np.nanmin(T, axis=1)

print R
print thresh
print v
```

prints

```
[[41 34 35 37 40 35]
 [14 35 33 40 21 39]
 [30 37 34 40 14 41]
 [13 41 27 40 37 23]]
[37 23 41 37]
[ 0.  1.  5.  1.]
```

e.g. in the first row, 41 is already bigger than threshold 37, so return value in `v` is 0; in the third row the last value actually matches the threshold, so return timestamp is 5.